# php array_sum returning first value only

Tags: php, array-sum

I'm fairly new at php, but this seems to be me overlooking something completely basic?

I have some values in a database column, that are comma separated like so:
1,2,3

When I try to get the sum of the values, I expect the echo of array_sum to be 6, but I only get returned the first value ie. "1"

```
echo $amount; //Gives 1,2,3 etc.

$amount_array = array($amount);
echo array_sum($amount_array); //Only prints "1"

print_r($amount); // shows 1,2,3
print_r($amount_array); // shows Array ( [0] => 1,2,3 )
```

Comment: $amount is a string. you're then stuffing that string into an array - that string becomes a SINGLE entry in the array. php won't magically split the string up into multiple components and make each of those components an array element... you need explode() for taht.

Comment: I prefer to use `var_dump` insted of `print_r` that shows types properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a string not an array, you have to split it using [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE) function:

```
$exploded =  explode ( "," , $amount_array);
var_dump($exploded);
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) the string needs to be converted to an array

You need to use the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function:

```
$amount_array = explode(',', $amount);
```

So you total code should be like this:

```
$amount_array = explode(',', $amount);
echo array_sum($amount_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_sum()` works by adding up the values in an array. You only have one key=>value pair in your array: key `0` with a value of `1,2,3`.

If you have a comma-separated list, and want that to be an array, I would use the `explode()` function to turn the list into the proper key=>value pairs that `array_sum()` would expect.

Try

```
$amount_array = explode(',',$amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not initialize an array the way you intend. You are passing in a comma-separated string, which is just a single argument. PHP doesn't automagically convert that string into separate arguments for you.

In order to convert a comma-separated string into an array of individual values you can break up the string with a function like [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), which takes a delimiter and a string as its arguments, and returns an array of the delimiter-separated values.

```
$amount_array = explode( ',', $amount ); // now $amount_array is the array you intended
```